# Taking a formula from a vector in R ("no terms component nor attribute")

Tags: r, vector

I have an R function from a bioinformatics package ([DESeq2](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/DESeq2.html)) that takes as one of its arguments a "formula" (I'm not sure I use the correct term for these things in R starting with "~"). I noticed that when I make a vector that contains formulas, the function fails if I give it an element of the vector.

```
# sample_table and data_dir are already defined at this point
design_1 <- ~ genotype
design_2 <- ~ treatment
designs <- c(design_1, design_2)

dds_raw <- DESeqDataSetFromHTSeqCount(
    sampleTable = sample_table,
    directory = data_dir,
    design = designs[1])
```

I get the following error in my actual code (which is a bit more complicated than the example above):

```
Error in terms.default(object, data = data) : 
  no terms component nor attribute
Calls: <Anonymous> ... model.matrix -> model.matrix.default -> terms -> terms.default
Execution halted
```

**What does this error mean?**

However, the following seems to work:

```
design_1 <- "~ genotype"
design_2 <- "~ treatment"
designs <- c(design_1, design_2)

dds_raw <- DESeqDataSetFromHTSeqCount(
    sampleTable = sample_table,
    directory = data_dir,
    design = formula(designs[1]))
```

As well as directly writing the formula when setting the argument:

```
dds_raw <- DESeqDataSetFromHTSeqCount(
    sampleTable = sample_table,
    directory = data_dir,
    design = ~ genotype
```

**Why is that so ? Can't formulas be put in a vector ?**

Comment: I can think of a couple things that might be going wrong, the first (very simple) thing I'd try is using `designs[[1]]` instead of `designs[1]` and see if that works. If it doesn't, then what's going wrong is a bit more complicated and may have to do with the environment attached to the formula.

Comment: Formulas cannot be put into vectors. They are not atomic types. They must be put into lists (look at `class(designs)` when you think you are making a vector -- it's a list). And you need to use `[[ ]]` to extract things from lists.

Comment: I tried to revert to my initial Error-generating case, to test the `[[ ]]` way, but somehow the error is different now: "Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable", whether I use `[ ]` or `[[ ]]`, and after the `[ ]` or `[[ ]]` operation is made (unless R is a lazy language: I actually pass `designs[[i]]` as parameter to a function that then passes the corresponding variable to `DESeqDataSetFromHTSeqCount`).

I have my code split between 3 files and I didn't git commit during my debugging experiments, so I don't know what changed.
Anyway, `class(designs)` indeed says it is a list.